# How to remove "Spotlight Search" placeholder in macOS spotlight?

Tags: macos, mac, macos-mojave, osx-leopard, macos-catalina

Pressing "command + space",i want to remove "Spotlight Search" placeholder text in it, i think its kind of disturbing. Is there any way do achieve this?

[Spotlight Search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GeuO.png)

Answer (score 1):

Based on my previous answer (which was addressing the wrong problem) and the op's comments there, it looks like this string is stored in `/System/Library/OnBoardingBundles/com.apple.onboarding.spotlightsearch.bundle/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/SpotlightSearch.strings` for English systems.  Similar/nearby location for other files.

However, you can no longer edit System files, AFAIK.  This article shows a way around it: https://www.howtogeek.com/230424/how-to-disable-system-integrity-protection-on-a-mac-and-why-you-shouldnt/

It involves modifying NVRAM settings, something I'm not willing to try.  But, if you are, also download this tools to edit those "binary" strings files: https://github.com/igorkulman/iOSLocalizationEditor

I used it to modify a copy of that `.strings` file, but I can't move it into place without also doing the NVRAM hack above.

If it works, let us know here!

Comment: i cant use that app edit it directly,


mv SpotlightSearch.strings /System/Library/OnBoardingBundles/com.apple.onboarding.spotlightsearch.bundle/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/



override rw-r--r--  root/wheel for /System/Library/OnBoardingBundles/com.apple.onboarding.spotlightsearch.bundle/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/SpotlightSearch.strings? (y/n [n]) y



mv: rename SpotlightSearch.strings to /System/Library/OnBoardingBundles/com.apple.onboarding.spotlightsearch.bundle/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/SpotlightSearch.strings: Read-only file system


shows read-only file system

Comment: Yes, I know, I tried that too. That’s why I included that link on the NVRAM settings needed to edit the System folder. Apple really doesn’t want us editing in there anymore...

Comment: i disabled SIP,and use ```mount -uw /``` ，then i can edit that file, delete "Spotlight Search",but after reboot, the text is still in that Input box

Answer (score 0):

System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Spotlight.  Mine is set to F4, or you could just turn it off.

[image]

Comment: i want hide "Spotlight Search" grey color placeholder  text in that input box when not input anything, not disable spotlight search

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood. I’m guessing that text is different in other countries/languages, so it’s likely that this is stored as a string inside a resource file. Open up Terminal and “cd” into /System (or /Library) and “grep -R” to find that string in a file. if it works, document it here, because you’ll likely need to redo that change with every macOS update.

Comment: i find a dir like below
"/System/Library/OnBoardingBundles/com.apple.onboarding.spotlightsearch.bundle/Contents/Resources"

dont know if this was,and many different language files there,but are binary files